# How to recreate an activity which has been brought to front of the stack using flag?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have two activities `ChooseTeamActivity` (say `A`) and `TeamDetailsActivity` (say `B`). Now Activity `A` contains a list of 30 teams. Clicking any one of the items opens its team details in Activity `B`. I am using the following code to open Activity `B`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeamDetailsActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Suppose I open details of *Team 1* in Activity `B` from Activity `A`. Then I go back to Activity `A` and now open details of *Team 2*. Since Activity `B` is already in the stack, it is reusing the activity `B` already in the stack but it is showing me the details of *Team 1* and not *Team 2*. How can I recreate this activity which has been brought to the front, so that I can see the details of *Team 2*?

Comment: When you leave `B` it gets destroyed....usually...and not reused. How do you go *back*?

Comment: ...which is why I am asking how you go back to activity `A`.

Comment: Why would it get destroyed and not remain in the stack? I am going to Activity A using the back button.

Comment: Pass the team in with the Intent. In Activity B you can get the team from the Intent and load the appropriate information.

Comment: I am doing it. Still not working.

Comment: Unless you override `onBackPressed` and do something else, this *will* destroy `B`. I'm talking about the hardware/software button on the bottom.

Comment: Oh yeah! Since Activity A has lot of pictures, I am not saving it on stack. I am overriding Activity B's onBackPressed() and I am checking there whether the previous activity was Activity A. If yes, then I am launching Activity A using intent.

Comment: Show how you update the view in activity B. If you get the correct team information inside activity B from activity A, the problem might be how you update the view.